# Como actualizar el contenido de un textarea a partir del texto que se ingresa en div

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Quiero actualizar el contenido de un textarea a partir del texto que se ingresa en div (contenteditable="true"). La idea es poder ir actualizando el elemento textarea  con el texto nuevo, es decir ir adicionando solo el contenido reciente del div en la parte final del textarea.

La idea es que lo enviado anteriormente al textarea no se modifique; solo se adicione la información nueva del div.

Lo que se busca es poder ir almacenando periódicamente solo informacion que se actualiza no el contenido completo.

---

La idea es que lo enviado anteriormente al textarea no se modifique; solo se adicione la información nueva del div.

Lo que se busca es poder ir almacenando periódicamente solo informacion que se actualiza no el contenido completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu textarea tiene un `id="testarea"` simplemente añades esto en el document ready:

```
$('.diveditable').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(isAlphanumeric(e.keyCode))
        $('#testarea').val(function(i, content){
            return content + e.key;
        });
});

function isAlphanumeric(keyCode){
    if((keyCode == 32 || //Espacio
        (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || //Números
        (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || //Mayúsculas
        (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122))  //Minúsculas
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Edito: He realizado las modificaciones para que se adecuen a tu aclaración. De esta manera tan solo se irá añadiendo contenido al textarea siempre y cuando se hayan pulsado letras/números, y nunca se borrará.

Comment: Esto no es un foro, te recomiendo que si quieres proporcionar más información edites tu preguntas o la pongas como comentarios, no en otra respuesta.

Comment: Ya debería funcionar como aclaraste

Comment: De acuerdo el codigo se ajusta, solo queda pendiente poder tolerar los espacios en el texto como validos.

Comment: para los espacios agrega este or ` || (keyCode == 32)` después de minúsculas y antes de cerrar el paréntesis envolvente.